# Issue with Category Name " type " only showing 404 for posts inside that category

Tags: wordpress, plesk, permalinks

I have a website that has a strange issue. Website is on WordPress

Permalink Structure to currently keep is: /%category%/%postname%/

if i keep this structure and make a category named " type " then any post inside that category will show a 404 page.

so this link suppose /type/test-post/

will start showing a 404 page.

But if we have any other categories added it will work fine.

I have checked all database, pages, posts, theme post types, turned on health check. disabled everything and only kept default theme and still the issue is there.

i have also tried default htaccess. but nothing is working. will really be grateful if someone has this same error or has some idea on how to solve this out.

Thank you